# How to retrieve the filepath from a Browse-Button with askopenfilename and write it to an entry widget with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm just started playing around with Tkinter. I would like to have a small window with an entry.widget and a browse button right next to it, where a file path can be entered or a file can be selected by clicking on the "Browse" button. Here is my first approach:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
#import os

master = Tk()

def callback():
    path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    print path

w = Label(master, text="File Path:")
e = Entry(master)
b = Button(master,text="Browse", command = callback)

w.pack(side=LEFT)
e.pack(side=LEFT)
b.pack(side=LEFT)

master.mainloop()
```

My problem is, I do not know how to write the file path to the entry widget after a file has been selected. I think it might work with something like

```
e.insert(path)
```

but I can't access path since it is only a local variable in the callback function. I already tried assigning it as a global variable but it didn't work out.

Thank you in advance for any advise.

Answer (score 3):

Using the 'insert':

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

master = Tk()


def callback():
    path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    e.delete(0, END)  # Remove current text in entry
    e.insert(0, path)  # Insert the 'path'
    # print path


w = Label(master, text="File Path:")
e = Entry(master, text="")
b = Button(master, text="Browse", command=callback)

w.pack(side=LEFT)
e.pack(side=LEFT)
b.pack(side=LEFT)

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Tkinter.StringVar` for your entry:

```
var = StringVar()
e = Entry(master, textvariable=var)
b = Button(master, text="Browse",
           command=lambda:var.set(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()))
```